# How to add a directory to PATH in Linux ? I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux - Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, paths

I am new at Linux and I am facing a problem.
I am trying to add the bin directory to the PATH in the Linux executing the command below:

```
$ export PATH="/opt/gcc-arm/bin:$PATH"
```

However, when I try to execute a command it returns me it was not found

```
Command 'arm-none-eabi-gcc' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install gcc-arm-none-eabi
```

How could I add this directory to Linux PATH or there is a way to access the User variables from Windows using the Linux?

Edit1: I just run `$PATH` and I got this:

```
bash: /opt/gcc-arm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program:
```

The Path to the file that I created is there (`/opt/gcc-arm/bin`), but I do not understand why the system cannot recognize it.

Edit2: I executed the command suggested by @steeldriver

> what is the result of `file /opt/gcc-arm/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc run`

The result is: `/opt/gcc-arm/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=7af6e16f1d030393cdf4a6e6007a0e554470f126, stripped`. But I have no idea what it means.

Edit3: Now the things start to work, first I use the command `sudo -s` and then

```
$ export PATH="/opt/gcc-arm/bin:$PATH".
```

After doing that I was able to run the commands from that PATH, however, when I close the Linux env and open again, it can not recognize those commands, so I have to include the PATH  again. 
Is there some solution to avoid entering the PATH every time when I reopen the Linux?

Edit4: I followed this tutorial from Youtube [Linux: Permanently set environment variables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvAYH5Qu_YQ), now my PATH is permanent.

I hope this can help someone else that face this same problem

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Have you executed the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` command in the same windows where you issued the `export` command? Is the file present in the path you added?

Comment: @Melebius, yes the file is present in the file even in the Windows as in the Linux and I executed it on Windows, it ran without issue.

Comment: @Melebius, first I worked with those commands on Windows, the path to them in Windows are C:\Users\arge10\Documents\stm32\opt\bin and worked perfectly.
 
Today I migrated to Linux, I created the same file on Linux environment in /opt/gcc-arm/bin. I tried to add this to Linux PATH, but no success running tthat command. I just ran $PATH on Linux and I got:
bash: /opt/gcc/arm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program:

Comment: How exactly did you create the file(s) in `/opt/gcc-arm/bin`? what is the result of `file /opt/gcc-arm/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc` ?

Comment: @steeldriver, So I downloaded it as .tar.bz2 file, then I moved it to the current file and extract it there using command tar xjf. This command you mentioned returned:
 /opt/gcc-arm/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=7af6e16f1d030393cdf4a6e6007a0e554470f126, stripped

Comment: @GustavoDaSilvaGhedim Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score -1):

As the output suggests, you should run the following in your terminal (if you have not already tried doing so):

```
sudo apt install gcc-arm-none-eabi
```

Comment: @ITGremlin this file is from a repository on Github, cannot be installed using (sudo apt install)

Comment: @gustavo-da-silva-ghedim [Does this help?](https://www.lifewire.com/installing-software-using-git-3993572)

Comment: @ITGremlin, It does not help, however, when I enter sudo - s and then I export the PATH to the desired folder those commands I won't work perfectly, the problem now is when I close the Linux environment and reopen it, it does not recognize the PATH that I added, so I have to enter it again every time I open the Linux.